# How to keep textfield data when navigating away and back to page

Tags: c#, arrays, windows-phone-7.1, storage, storing-data

I am writing a golfing application. Each person enters his score in a textbox for each hole and then navigate to another page optionally. 
The problem I am having is that I want the numbers to stay there when I click to another page and then come back to that page. How can this be done?

This is my code for my textboxes and textblocks:

```
private void Calculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    int x1 = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out x1);
    int x2 = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out x2);
    int x3 = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out x3);
    int x4 = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out x4);
    int x5 = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out x5);
    int x6= 0;
    Int32.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out x6);
    int x7 = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(textBox7.Text, out x7);
    int x8 = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out x8);
    int x9 = 0;
    Int32.TryParse(textBox9.Text, out x9);


    int[] totalScore = new int[10];
    totalScore[0] = x1;
    totalScore[1] = x2;
    totalScore[2] = x3;
    totalScore[3] = x4;
    totalScore[4] = x5;
    totalScore[5] = x6;
    totalScore[6] = x7;
    totalScore[7] = x8;
    totalScore[8] = x9;
    int sum = totalScore.Sum();
    TotalBlock.Text = sum.ToString();


    }
```

Comment: It'd be useful to see more code, namely code showing you changing to the next 'page'. Also can you describe more on how you are changing pages. I can't really offer advice until i see more.

Comment: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967548(v=vs.105).aspx) might help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> A page is instantiated when you navigate to it (assuming you are
>   running on Silverlight). When you navigate away from it the state will
>   be saved in a stack. If you navigate back (by calling the GoBack
>   method on the NavigationService class) the page will be resumed from
>   its state, without calling the constructor.
>
> However, if you navigate away from an existing page, and re-navigate
>   to the page by calling the Navigate method, a brand new instance of
>   the page is instantiated, and thus the constructor will be called
>   again.

See also: [Windows phone 7 - the page life cycle](http://jesseliberty.com/2011/07/27/page-statestep-by-step/)

This means if you are using a navigate method all of your fields are empty because a new instance of the page is created.
If you want to keep the state of the `TextBlock` control you have to store the content temporary. You can use the `IsolatedStorageSettings` for this purpose, by adding the following using statement:

```
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
```

You can now save a string (in your case the `TextBlock` content) to the isolated storage like this:

```
public void SaveStringObject()
{
    var settings = IsolatedStorageSettings.ApplicationSettings;
    settings.Add("myContent", "foobar");
}
```

After calling the `SaveStringObject` method in your navigate method you need to save the settings by calling the [IsolatedStorageSettings.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragesettings.save%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) method.

If you come back to the page containing the TextBlock control you can use this code to retrieve the content of your TextBlock control:

```
TotalBlock.Text = settings["myContent"].ToString();
```

The posted code fragments are not complete. You can get a nice sample of using the IsolatedStorage in action right here: [IsolatedStorage Sample](http://www.jeffblankenburg.com/2010/10/15/31-days-of-windows-phone-day-15-isolated-storage/)